# custom event for mouse coordinates

Tags: javascript, iframe, mouseevent, custom-events

I'm creating iFrame and in that iFrame script I need to catch mouse coordinates after creation (in very start). I was hoping that it's possible with custom event.

I tried

```
var myEvent = new Event('mouseC');

document.addEventListener('mouseC', function(e){
    console.log('my event is working');
    console.log('mouse x is '+e.pageX);
    console.log('mouse y is '+e.pageY);
});

document.dispatchEvent(myEvent);
```

console is displaying 'my event is working', but mouse coordinates are *undefined*.
 I tried wrapping it in `window.onload`, and I also tried `screenX` and `clientX`... always undefined
How can I catch mouse coordinates in newly created iFrame imedietly after creation?

...btw, `mousemove` event is working and writing coordinates when mouse is moved over new iFrame.
Could I somehow move mouse for just 1px to trigger that event?

Answer (score 0):

```
 iframElement = document.getElementBy...("...");
 document.addEventListener("click", function(evt,iframElement){

 var x = evt.pageX - iframElement.offset.left;
 var y = evt.pageY - iframElement.offset.top;

 console.log(x+" , "+y);

});
```

it might work

Comment: no, I need to catch it from iFrame... not outside of it.

Answer (score 0):

```
var value =parent.frames[FRAME_NAME].frameElement.offsetParent;
var x = 0, y = 0;
while (value)
{
x += value .offsetLeft;
y += value .offsetTop;
value = value .offsetParent;
//console x anf y...
}
```

console x and y you can get co ordinates of mouse inside iframe.

Comment: i'm getting this error : "Uncaught SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin "chrome-extension://xxxx......" from accessing a frame with origin "http://stackoverflow.com".  The frame requesting access has a protocol of "chrome-extension", the frame being accessed has a protocol of "http". Protocols must match."